# Golang Gorilla mux with http.FileServer returning 404

Tags: go, gorilla

The problem I'm seeing is that I'm trying to use the `http.FileServer` with the Gorilla mux Router.Handle function.

This doesn't work (the image returns a 404)..

```
myRouter := mux.NewRouter()
myRouter.Handle("/images/", http.StripPrefix("/images/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(HomeFolder + "images/"))))
```

this works (the image is shown ok)..

```
http.Handle("/images/", http.StripPrefix("/images/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(HomeFolder + "images/"))))
```

Simple go web server program below, showing the problem...

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "io"
    "log"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

const (
    HomeFolder = "/root/test/"
)

func HomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, htmlContents)
}

func main() {

    myRouter := mux.NewRouter()
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/", HomeHandler)
    //
    // The next line, the image route handler results in 
    // the test.png image returning a 404.
    // myRouter.Handle("/images/", http.StripPrefix("/images/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(HomeFolder + "images/"))))
    //
    myRouter.Host("mydomain.com")
    http.Handle("/", myRouter)

    // This method of setting the image route handler works fine.
    // test.png is shown ok.
    http.Handle("/images/", http.StripPrefix("/images/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(HomeFolder + "images/"))))

    // HTTP - port 80
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
        fmt.Printf("ListenAndServe:%s\n", err.Error())
    }
}

const htmlContents = `<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test page</title>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p align="center">
        <img src="/images/test.png" height="640" width="480">
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
`
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

*I posted this on golang-nuts discussion group and got [this solution from Toni Cárdenas](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/gCxMpMabVJQ/hE7q3rHqkSEJ) ...*

The standard net/http ServeMux (which is the standard handler you are using when you use `http.Handle`) and the mux Router have different ways of matching an address.

See the differences between http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux and http://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux.

So basically, `http.Handle('/images/', ...)` matches '/images/whatever', while `myRouter.Handle('/images/', ...)` *only* matches '/images/', and if you want to handle '/images/whatever', you have to ...

**Option 1** - Use a regular expression match in your router

```golang
myRouter.Handle("/images/{rest}",
     http.StripPrefix("/images/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(HomeFolder + "images/"))))
```

**Option 2** - Use the PathPrefix method on your router:

```golang
myRouter.PathPrefix("/images/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/images/", 
     http.FileServer(http.Dir(HomeFolder + "images/"))))
```

Comment: +1 #2 has been successful for me in a current project (before I stumbled upon this answer.  just reassuring the reader(s) that #2 is what I am using and works).

Comment: Just a note to add, please remember if you are a golang newb like me, golang does not like statements as formatted by in #2.  I needed combine all three lines into one line (no changes in syntax, only changes in whitespace) before golang would stop complaining about expecting commas.  #2 is the right answer, it is just formated in such a way that will cause problems for newbies and novices like myself.

Comment: You're right, I had to put the make the statement a single line.

Comment: Thank you so much for putting me out  of hours of misery, the PathPrefix and StripPrefix thing worked for me, I went from `r.Handle("/", fs)` to a `r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/", fs))`

Comment: @SamGamgee - you can go one step further and drop the `http.StripPrefix()` so that you end up with `r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(fs)`

Answer (score 0):

As of May 2015 [gorilla/mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux) package still have no version releases. But problem is different now. It is not that `myRouter.Handle` does not match url and needs regexp, it does! But `http.FileServer` requires prefix to be removed from url. Below example works fine.

```
ui := http.FileServer(http.Dir("ui"))
myRouter.Handle("/ui/", http.StripPrefix("/ui/", ui))
```

Note, there is no /ui/**{rest}** in abowe example. You may also wrap `http.FileServer` into logger gorilla/handler and see request to coming to FileServer and response 404 going out.

```
ui := handlers.CombinedLoggingHandler(os.Stderr,http.FileServer(http.Dir("ui"))
myRouter.Handle("/ui/", ui) // getting 404
// works with strip: myRouter.Handle("/ui/", http.StripPrefix("/ui/", ui))
```

Comment: The default `Handle` method of `router` still creates a `route` the same way as before. I tried the method you stated above and `"/ui/"` will not match all paths with the `"/ui/"` prefix. @dodgy_coder's solution is correct. Either include the regex with the default `Handler` method or use `PathPrefix`