# Golang http.FileServer returns 404 not found

Tags: go, http

Having this simple snippet:

```
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./web/js"))
    http.Handle("/js/", http.StripPrefix("/js/", fs))
```

and going to `/js/` actually lists the files, but when I try to open the actual file it says `404 Not Found`

```
$ curl http://localhost:8100/js/
<pre>
<a href="test.js">test.js</a>
</pre>

$ curl http://localhost:8100/js/test.js
404 page not found
```

Any suggestions? It seems like a super trivial issue.

Comment: make sure you are running the binary  from where the "web" directory is

Comment: The code you've shared works as expected. https://imgur.com/a/6uC6vna

Comment: @SarathSadasivanPillai running the binary from a different location only changes the relative path of the files, which doesn't work.

Comment: @mkopriva this is also what I expected, so that is why I am confused of what is going on.

Comment: @Luminance if you dumb it down to the same code that's in the screenshot, and launch the server from the parent directory of `./web`, do you still get 404?

Comment: @mkopriva, so dumbing it down, like your example works and it helped me figure out that it is my mistake by not providing a fill context that I was actually using gorilla/mux. I though it is completely compatible, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was not in the code snippet, but rather obscuring details like using `gorilla/mux` which serves files differently as pointed in this solution:

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21251658/7105071)

TLDR:

```
import  "github.com/gorilla/mux"

// snip

router := mux.NewRouter()
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./web/js"))
router.Handle("/js/{.js}", http.StripPrefix("/js/", fs))
```